# How to Update a Microsoft Teams Bot Messaging Endpoint with code?

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

Currently there are two portal options to update the endpoint for a Teams Bot:

1. https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/bots (works intermittently)
2. https://dev.botframework.com/bots

How can we update this from the command line / with code?

I'm aware of the `az bot` commands (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/bot?view=azure-cli-latest) but this appears to be for managing resources deployed under 'Bot Services', and not bots created via the 'Bot Framework'.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to update the messaging endpoint in Azure Bot service?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft This is a bot created via dev.botframework.com. My understanding, that could well be wrong, is that the bot service is something else.

Answer (score 0):

I had a chat just last week with someone else about this - see [How to add authentication to a Bot Framework v4 project without Azure Bot Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73066864/how-to-add-authentication-to-a-bot-framework-v4-project-without-azure-bot-servic/73068360#73068360)

In essence, the "bot portal" is basically just provisioning things for you behind the scenes in the Azure portal in any case - I'd suggest rather just doing everything in Azure directly. In any, the Microsoft Bot "Framework" conceptually consists of two pieces - code samples + SDKs, and a backend core service that underlies every bot. As a result, bot "Framework" bots *also* have a "Bot Service" backend. Note that, by itself, this does not include *hosting* for the bot, just a central service registration to handle the traffic routing, security, etc.

Please have a read of the blog post I refer in that other question - it (hopefully) gives a good overview.

In answer to your question directly - az bot should be fine to use, specifically https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/bot?view=azure-cli-latest#az-bot-update

Comment: Thanks Hilton. How funny! I'd just read your blog article earlier this week. Re: the other post and your comment "The both go into the same database behind the scenes"; I feel there's some inconsistency by Microsoft making it very confusing. If we go to ["Bot Services"](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_ProjectOxford/AppliedAIHub/~/BotServices) the only thing you can do is create a bot using a product from the marketplace. Instead, you have to search for 'Azure Bot'. When creating a bot there like most resources in Azure you choose a resource group (etc) and this then becomes...

Comment: visible to the `az bot` CLI (and thus I suspect, you're able to update the messaging endpoint using it). However this bot is not made visible in the bot framework portals listed in the original post. Conversely, when creating bots via the bot framework portal, these don't appear directly in the Azure Portal, have no visible resource group, and therefore can't be queried with `az bot`.

Comment: To add even more funky behaviour to the mix, when viewing [dev.botframework.com](https://dev.botframework.com/bots) it'll list a bot created via that portal very quickly. If I wait about 5 minutes, it'll eventually display an old bot which does exist in the Azure Portal in a resource group but was created before "Azure Bot" was a thing and is actually a combination of an app registration, function app, service bus namespace and app service plan. There are so many ways to interface with their "bot" products that it becomes a hurdle to start.

Comment: oh that's wierd indeed. Are you sure you're logged in to both places with the same account? in any case, I'd suggest sticking with the Azure portal...

Comment: Yes, and as a global admin. I'll leave this post open until MSFT have replied back but I suspect that there's no way to update the endpoint for a bot created via the bot framework itself, but only for those created as an 'Azure Bot' via the Azure Portal. If that's the case I'll post an answer to that effect. Thank you for your help, and for your blog post :)

Comment: Right now the only way you can update your endpoint is @Hilton as mentioned above az Bot.
Ref Doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/bot?view=azure-cli-latest#az-bot-update